# Change publish button text from option page

Tags: php, wordpress

I know how to change the text from a post type, but it is not working in option page from my custom post type:

```
function change_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {
if ( $text == 'Publish' || $text == 'Update' )
    return 'Export';

return $translation;                                                          
}
```

Comment: `function change_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {
if ( $text == 'Publish' || $text == 'Update' )
{
    return 'Export';
}

return $translation;                                                          
}` Basically you are saying IF $export contains some text, then return 'Export', else it will skip your IF and it will return $translation. Why is this not working? Try the code I wrote first. I've added '{}'. Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: can you show screenshot where you would like to change text?

Comment: i managed to change the label of publish to export but not the text of the button http://prntscr.com/hb1d7w